# Is there a wxWidgets framework for C?

Tags: c, user-interface

My understanding is that [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org) is for a number of programming languages (C++, Python, Perl, and C#/.NET) but that does not include C. Is there a similar framework for the C programming language, or is this not something that C is used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/). I believe wxWidgets implementation for linux is written in GTK+.

Comment: GTK is not native to mac or windows so its not really a replacement for wxwidgets

Answer (score 7):

If you don't mind working with older libraries there are quite a few. For example, there's a no-frills GUI kit for Ansi-C called [IUP](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/).  Also, check out [this list](http://www.atai.org/guitool/#free_c) -- Search on that page for 'C API'.  I think the most modern and well-known is the above-mentioned GTK+.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously No, Because it has predefined classes but if you insist you can try GTK which is for C.